# Drawing tadpole diagram using feynmp

Tags: feynmf

I have a basic question, how can I draw a tadpole using feynmp?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.  You need run latex on this twice to get the output.  I obtained this by following the types of examples given at http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/~taku/osx/feynmp.html

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}
\unitlength=1mm

\begin{fmffile}{example}
  \begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
    \fmfleft{i}
    \fmfright{o}
    \fmf{photon}{i,v1}
    \fmf{plain,left}{v1,o,v1}
  \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```